# CSS fit image to the container depending on the height or width

Tags: html, css, containers

I have a container that has size, say 600 for width and 400 for height.  Also I have 2 images one has size 600(width) * 1 and one has dimension 1 * 400(height).  Is there a way that I fit the first image to the container using **width** or max-width and the second one using **height** or max-height?  Thanks.

Comment: post some code which you tried sofar?

Comment: Would be nice if you could show us what you currently have

Comment: I search around and found many possible answers but none of them worked for me.. let me search their post a bit..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `img` tag is the only element that can auto scale to match the image size.

Depending on your scenario you might be able to use a container width a fixed width & height and use `background-size: contain`.

Otherwise you have to use javascript and do the math yourself.

> Is there a way that I fit the first image to the container using
> width or max-width and the second one using height or max-height?

In short: no.

Here's an example with the `img` tag: http://jsfiddle.net/sn3uu0uw/2/

Comment: It is possible to scale a div up in width to fit an image using `display: inline-block` and `width: auto`. Or well I've fit multiple contents in an auto-width scaling div anyways. An image should be no different if it has dimensions

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand Can you give an example? I was not able to reproduce that: http://jsfiddle.net/sn3uu0uw/ Or do you mean a img tag in that described container?

Comment: I do mean an img tag indeed, I probably misunderstood the question. With an image tag it should be possible tho ;) I'll see if I can get that working for completeness

Comment: Well I don't see how that differs from my answer than?

Comment: Since it uses an img tag rather than a background image. anyways: http://jsfiddle.net/sn3uu0uw/3/ updated with what I meant ;)

Comment: Well it doesn't seem to work for me since it's not scaling the image at all (I changed the max width to 600px, but it will just overflow. http://jsfiddle.net/sn3uu0uw/4/

Comment: Yeah it's a useless usecase, as mentioned I probably misunderstood the question and added things for completeness. It has an advantage but it's not what the OP wants anyways, my bad

Comment: It works perfectly for me. I was only thinking about what to do with img.. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

turns out there's another way to do this.

```
<img style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain;" />
```

will do the work. It's CSS3 stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
.body {
    background: url("img_flwr.gif");
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
    the above class will good enough for 600px width image.similarly write another class with background-size: auto 100%; which should be applicable for 400px height image.Apply the classes using jquery.
```